# Rails 2 cache view helper not saving to memcached

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, memcached

I have a block

```
<% cache 'unique_key', 60.minutes.from_now do %>
  ...
  <% begin %>
    ...
  <% rescue %>
    ...
  <%end>
<% end %>
```

and I'm trying to make the implementation more robust by only caching (and thus allowing the user to see) the rescue message if there isn't a previous value already in the cache.  Currently, if the response in the begin block sends back an error for any reason, I'm caching the user viewed error message.  I would prefer to fall back onto the old cached data.  The problem that I can't get past is -

Where is `cache` storing the data?

Every time I try `Rails.cache.read 'unique_key'`, I get `nil` back.  Is `cache` not storing the value in memcached?  Is there a way that I can dump the cache to screen?

I couldn't follow the rails source.  It seemed to me the the `fragment_for` method in `cache` was a rails 3 thing, and thus, I didn't debug further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by using the fetch method.  I used

```
<% Rails.cache.fetch('unique_key', :expires_in => 60.minutes){  
   begin
     ...
   rescue
     ...
   end
} %>
```

When I did this, I could successfully find the key.  I'm still not sure why I couldn't find the cached data after adding the `fragment_cache_key` that I found, but using `Rails.cache.fetch` seemed to do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

The `cache` view helper constructs a cache key based on the arguments you give it. At a minimum it adds the prefix 'views/' to the key.

You can use the `fragment_cache_key` helper to find out what cache key rails is using for any of your calls to `cache`. If you just want to grab what is currently stored, `read_fragment` does that. Of course with your particular usage, if your block is executed again it is because the 60 minutes are up: the cached value has been deleted from memcache.

With the memcache store  you can't list all of the keys currently in the store - it's just something thy memcached itself doesn't support.

Comment: When I used `fragment_cache_key('a')`, I got back 'views/a'.  However, 'views/unique_key' is still returning nil.  Is there something else happening perhaps?

Comment: Do you have caching turned on ?(it's off in development mode by default)

Comment: I suppose I don't actually know.  I'm requiring mem_cache_store and running memcached.  There wasn't much activity though

Comment: So caching was enabled, an interesting problem that I ran into though, was that I couldn't see traffic because running `memcached -vv` wasn't binding to the correct port.  When I tried to manually set it with `memcached -m 500 -l 127.0.0.1 -p 11211 -vv`, there was a problem binding to the specified port.  To solve this, I had to exit the console and server, and then kill a background process (found by `pgrep 11211 | xargs ps`).  Then run the memcached command and restart everything.  I could then see cache hits/misses flying by